# How do you fix a MySQL “Incorrect key file” error when you can’t repair the table?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a rather large query that is supposed to run nightly to populate a table.  I'm getting an error saying `Incorrect key file for table '/var/tmp/#sql_201e_0.MYI'; try to repair it` but the storage engine I'm using (whatever the default is, I guess?) doesn't support repairing tables.

how do I fix this so I can run the query?  We are under pressure to get this table loaded for a client.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an actual table of yours, that's a temporary table created by the db to do some work.  There's probably a left over tmp table file from a previous operation that's conflicting with whatever you're trying to do now.  I'd suggest just stopping the server and running `rm /var/tmp/*.MY{I,D}`.

Comment: I tried that and it said there were no files like it, but I'm still getting that same error.

Comment: The error seems to be because the tables that I'm joining and running transformations on has thousands upon thousands of records.  But there's no way to trim it down or modify the query, so I'm stuck on how to fix the error without changing the query or the data.